# Multiple dialogs at the same time

Tags: android, dialog, popup

There is a dialog box with some buttons on top of my activity. When user presses a button, network request occurs, and a progress dialog supposed to be shown. So there must be at least two dialogs at a time, which is not possible (I guess).
I see 2 possible solutions here:

- when a button is pressed, hide main dialog and show progress dialog
- wrap everything that pops up in a single dialog and manage it by hand

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends what's happening AFTER the network request was done.

From a "clean" view, I'd recommend #1 and keep all "actions" as seperate as possible. This leads into smaller code segments for each action which can be taken.

Depending on your needs (after network request, still have be inside the dialog), #2 could be the way to go, too. It's just a lot more work to to. In this case, just put some (View.INVISIBLE) progressbar inside the Dialog and show/hide on demand while your network request (hopefully in AsyncTask) is running. Also setEnabled(false) your Buttons for that time. Take care of dialog cancellation by user request (back button).

Comment: Dialogs aren't static - they are being loaded from server. Activity content view also is. Kinda like a browser. So I think it's important for user to be able to see a full previous state of an application while waiting for the next one.

Comment: Ok, what about this: You dont use a Dialog, but you use an Activity which LOOKS like a Dialog. To do so, add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your manifest for that activity. Your Activity then is NOT fullscreen anymore and overlays the calling Activity. Now feel free to call a ProgressDialog over your fake-"DialogActivity".

Comment: Reopening my question - I got 2 dialogs showing simultaneously (so it's possible though). But it looks like their z-order depends on the order in which they were created (not show()'n, created). Don't want to recreate my waiting dialog every time.. Any thoughts on how to change the order?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you posted another question on top.
If you go with the Activity-in-Dialog-style, you don't need to recreate the waiting dialog, do you? For the z-order in showing multiple real dialogs at the same time, I don't have any idea. As far as I remember, the modal Dialogs get added to the main ViewGroup at creation time as visibility GONE and shown on demand. Changing the order of the already created ones would need to directly access and change the window's ViewGroup - which is hacking around system internals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's another option - dynamically (runtime) add `ProgressBar` into your dialog and then immediately after `ProgressBar` completion remove it.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/myText"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/progressBarHere"/>
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then in code smth like:

```
final TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.progressBarHere);
ProgressBar pb=new ProgressBar(activity);
//...
tr.addView(pb);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, but it would be too complicated - "please wait" window may arrive when a dialog is not showing (most frequently it is so), or may stay on screen before it's shown and after that too... I think the only way now is to have an "overlay" view as a dialog, with other stuff embedded.

Comment: By the way, isn't there any better way to make "overlay", that lives independet of the main content? It seems like dialog painting isn't that optimized on android

Comment: I told the howto in my answers comment ;)